# 'Realm' or 'domain'?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

In the both sentences bellow, for me both the words 'realm' and 'domain' work in AmE. I need your confirmation; do you agree that these two words mean the same in each one of the examples bellow and using each one would not change the meaning of the sentence in the following senses:

> - This question can be answered in the realm / domain of psychology.
> - On the internet you can find everything in the realm / domain of medicine.

Comment: I'm not a native, neither sure, but if I were you I would have used "scope".

Comment: No. First there are no true synonyms. This is true in the phrases you create here. The 'realm of medicine' and the 'domain of medicine' do not have the same meaning in your sentence. In my opinion, *realm* (meaning 'sphere') works better in both sentences; domain calls to mind a more physical kingdom. Or at least it does not as easily correspond to *sphere* for me. It is a question of context which word sounds better. Words have a symbiotic relationship to their context and are not wooden pegs to  neatly pound into any available hole without a subtle shift in meaning happening.

Comment: Thank you @CarSmack; but I heard that 'realm of psychology' and 'domain of medicine' are two fixed expressions! :-/
It sounds a little puzzling to me now! :-(

Comment: The sentence also is not constructed well: *On the internet you can find everything in the domain of medicine* can mean that everything on the internet falls within or under medicine's domain.

Comment: *Everything in the domain of medicine can be found on the internet* is also untrue. And your first sentence works better with *within*.

Comment: @CarSmack On this forum, I generally avoid commenting on the truthfulness of statements used as examples. There have been plenty of examples given from articles about politics or religion that I totally disagree with, and I try to just keep my mouth shut on the underlying subject and discuss the grammar. (Though, I admit, I do occasionally deviate from that principle.) :-)

Comment: Yes @Jay  but I thought there is a difference between talking about a truth-statement alleged by an example sentence of the asker (this political party sucks), and talking about whether an assertion made in a statement can be true semantically. Part of the indicative is to provide information. A-friend asks about the meaning of the sentence. And to me *the semantics of 'the domain of medicine' as used in a sentence* is not a politically charged topic. *shrug*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're apparently getting some disagreement on this one.

I'd say either "realm" or "domain" works in both your sentences. In either case it's something of a metaphor: "realm" and "domain" both literally mean "an area ruled over", like you could say, "This is the realm of the king of England" or "This is the domain of the king of England."

If you look at thefreedictionary.com, in the second definition of "realm" they give the example "realm of science", and the second definition of "domain" they give the example "domain of history". Both sound to me like exactly the same idea you are trying to convey.

Comment: "Domain" might be a little more explicit in terms of the "king's" governance, but I agree that both work fine in both AmE and BrE.

Answer (score 1):

You can technically use "realm" or "domain" in either of these sentences, but the word "realm" suggests something like a kingdom, such as "knights of the realm".  It has an old British feel.

"Domain" on the other hand is used more often and is more benign.  It suggests a more mathematical or scientific scope.

Answer (score 0):

"Realm" and "Domain" have technical meanings in the "field" of computer networking (including the Internet).

In both of your examples, "field" makes more sense than "realm" or "domain".